# create when click on option in select tag and check value create a input

Tags: javascript, angular

im trying to create a application with angular 2 , i have a form and select tag and option.i want when user click on each option check option's value and if for example value was equalto "aaa" an input field generate bottom of select tag.
i trying to much but cant resolve this problem :)

I'll really appreciate if someone can clarify on the above listed concerns I have.

Thanks...

```
  <select name="delivery_architecture" class="form-control testing">
          <option selected="selected">plz select</option>
          <option value="static">static</option>
          <option value="dynamic">dynamic</option>
          <option value="aaa" >aaa</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fill an array when an option is selected and then generate input elements using `*ngFor`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
  <select name="delivery_architecture" class="form-control testing" (change)="addInput($event.target.value)">
    <option selected="selected">plz select</option>
    <option value="static">static</option>
    <option value="dynamic">dynamic</option>
    <option value="aaa" >aaa</option>
  </select>

  <div *ngFor="#inp of inputs" >{{inp.name}}<input [ngModel]="inp.value"></div>
  <div><button (click)="showValues()">show values</button></div>

  <div>values: {{values}}</div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  inputs = [];
  addInput(name) {
    this.inputs.push({name: name, value: ''});
  }
}
```

The values written into the input elements are stored in the array as well.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0vgWoC?p=preview)